# Select Query - Rows with identifier in new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query on the db of a shopping cart that involves a few outer joins that returns something like this (heavily simplified):

```
Orderid |   Customer Name | Product | Image
 1      |      John       |  Prod1  | x.jpg
 1      |      John       |  Prod2  | e.jpg
 2      |      Paul       |  Prod3  | r.jpg
 3      |      Ringo      |  Prod1  | x.jpg
```

I would like the results to come out something like this

```
Orderid | Customer Name | Product1 | Image1 | Product2 | Image 2
  1     |      John     |   Prod1  |  x.jpg | Prod2    | e.jpg
  2     |      Paul     |   Prod3  |  r.jpg | NULL     | NULL
  3     |      Ringo    |   Prod1  |  x.jpg | NULL     | NULL
```

Is this possible?

My previous query used a GROUP_CONCAT and had the result as a blob but I didn't find it useful to work with.

Comment: Just don't do this with database, database logic should be as simple as possible.

Comment: If this is SQL Server you can use PIVOT, but why you would want to handle business logic inside a query is beyond me.

Comment: The purpose is to create a csv that can be used for an abandoned cart list including products. I've been running the queries in phpmyadmin to try to get the results I'm after. Ideally it will be built into a module of some description later so I could use php to sort the data.

Comment: do you really need the image lobs?

Comment: why would the product1 column have a Prod3 value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reliably get all of the products into a ***varying*** number of columns, you would need to use a `PIVOT` feature as present in DBMSs like SQL Server, Oracle, etc.

In the case of MySQL, that sort of feature is not available and the best way to generate a CSV straight from the query (as you mentioned in the comments to your question) would be to use `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

The reason why you had "blob" data in your `GROUP_CONCAT()` before was because you were trying to concatenate two different data types into the string, and thus the phpMyAdmin was automatically converting it to `[BLOB]`. You must have been concatenating various integer values(ID's, prices, etc.) along with string values. What you must do is `CAST()` the integer values to strings within your `GROUP_CONCAT()` so that PMA doesn't convert to blob. More info on [CAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).

Depending on what version of PMA you have, it may or may not convert to `[BLOB]`. If it does, you could always expand `+options` and check "*Show blob contents*" and it will show the expected result.

Just based on your above example (in addition to `product_id` to illustrate `CAST()`, you could do something like:

```
SELECT
    order_id,
    customer_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(CAST(product_id AS CHAR(6)), '|||', product, '|||', image) SEPARATOR ':::') AS order_products
FROM 
    orders
GROUP BY
    order_id,
    customer_name
```

This would give you a result set along the lines of:

```
Orderid | Customer Name | order_products 
  1     |      John     |   1|||Prod1|||x.jpg:::2|||Prod2|||e.jpg
  2     |      Paul     |   3|||Prod3|||r.jpg
  3     |      Ringo    |   1|||Prod1|||x.jpg
```

Then depending on the language you're using to build your application, you can "explode" the `order_products` string into arrays. First explode on the delimiter `:::` to separate products, then for each product, explode again on the delimiter `|||` to separate that product's details.

I use those particular delimiters because commas can be present in fields like the title, etc. and you would not want your script to separate the string in the wrong places. This possibility of erroneous separation is one of the major downsides to using `GROUP_CONCAT()`, so you must decide which delimiters would be best to use based on the unlikelihood that they would be present within the field values.

Also, watch out for nullable fields when using `CONCAT`. For example, say for each product that the `image` field wasn't required and could contain `NULL`. If one part of `CONCAT()` is `NULL`, then the entire concatted string will become `NULL`.

So for whichever field is nullable, you would want to use `COALESCE()` on the field to prevent `NULL`s being passed to `CONCAT()`. (e.g. `CONCAT(product, '|||', COALESCE(image, 'NoImage'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with pure mysql, for the following reasons:

- Impossibility to use pivots
- Impossibility to loop over a certain set of values (under oracle, you could connect by and loop over the columns with a name like 'product' to build as many temporary tables as different products)

As a workaround, you could programmatically generate your query; for each product found, concatenate a join to the query:

```
select orderid, customer_name, product1, image1, producti, imagei, productn, imagen
from table t
   inner join table t1 on t1.product = 'product1' and t1.order_id = t.order_id
   inner join table ti on ti.product = 'producti' and ti.order_id = t.order_id
   inner join table tn on tn.product = 'productn' and tn.order_id = t.order_id
```

all this is highly theoretical since I don't know anything about your model.

Hope it helps.
rgds.